# Using Swift library in Ionic project

Tags: android, ios, swift, ionic-framework

I am working on new application which use BLE to connect with custom device. I wrote some kind of parser in Swift which can take array of bytes (which I get from peripheral) and translate it into objects. I use this objects in iOS app to do some UI changes.

In the future I want to add support for Android.

I am going to use a Ionic to make shareable UI for both Android and iOS but I have a problem with my parser. What should I do:

1. Is is possible to use Swift library as 3rd in Ionic for both iOS and Android? How? (my parser doesn't use iOS SDK, it is clear business logic)
2. Should I write my parser in Java and use both Swift and Java?
3. Any other way to reuse my parser code? C/C++? Something else?

Comment: With `Kotlin` and `Swift` similarity I would consider maintaining those for the parser. With some autoconversion between them perhaps.

Comment: yea, but I will need to keep two versions of parser

Comment: If you'd write the parser in pure `C` there will be some overhead for creating Swift model objects. Stay away from `C++` if you don't have any 3rd party libs using it. I do believe bridging `Java` to `Swift` for such task would be an overkill, I'd go for something more lightweight like `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same parser code for both platforms, iOS and Android, you will have to implement it in the hybrid part of the application, either in javascript or typescript. I don't know of any way of using Swift for Android or Java for iOS. There is the possibility of creating your parser in C or C++ and compiling it into a .so lib for android and a .dylib for iOS but going that way in an ionic/cordova application is always a pain with many pitfalls to take care of.